# Could not locate a Flask application. You did not provide the "FLASK_APP" environment variable, and a "wsgi.py" or "app.py" module was not found i

Tags: flask

Check app.py Content: Make sure your app.py script contains the necessary code to create the Flask app instance. It should have something like this at the top of the script:
PS D:\COVID> python -m flask run
Usage: python -m flask run [OPTIONS]
Try 'python -m flask run --help' for help.

Error: Could not import 'app'.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Rather than just providing the error message, please edit your post to include your project's file structure, the contents of your `app.py` file, and the command you are using to init your app.

Comment: As explained in the [documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/quickstart/#a-minimal-application), to specify where your application is, use the parameter --app followed by the name of the relevant file. To start in debug mode add the additional parameter --debug. Assuming the application is named `app.py`: `python -m flask --app app.py --debug run`